# Real part of an analytic function

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

I'd like to know how to take the real part (of the power series representation) of an analytic function with the goal of showing the (real part of the analytic) function is real analytic.

I know this may seem trivial but I haven't been able to convince myself that that's the case.

Comment: What have you tried? What definition of "real analytic" did you use?

Comment: $f(z)=\sum a_nz^n$ then $\bar f(z)=\sum \bar a_n \bar z^n$ so $\Re f(z)=\sum \Re a_n (z^n+\bar z^n)+i\sum \Im a_n (z^n-\bar z^n)$ and notice that $z^n+\bar z^n=2 \Re (x+iy)^n$ is a real polynomial in $x,y$ and same $z^n-\bar z^n =2i \Im z^n$ is also real polynomial in $x,y$ times an $i$; by absolute convergence, one can rerrange the terms

Comment: @Somos the definition I'm using involves the ability to express the function using multi-indices as a power series with real coefficients.

Comment: @Conrad I appreciate it. Your answer considering conjugates and the other answer using polar coordinates definitely saved me from some painful algebra.

Comment: happy to be of help

Answer (score 1):

I will show an example with the power series for $e^z,\,z\in\mathbb{C}$. The power series is
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(re^{i\varphi})^n}{n!}.$$
Here $r$ is the magnitude of $z$ and $\varphi$ the phase angle. Note that $\operatorname{Re}(z_1+z_2)=\operatorname{Re}(z_1)+\operatorname{Re}(z_2),$ so
$$\operatorname{Re}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{r^ne^{i\varphi n}}{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\operatorname{Re}\frac{r^ne^{i\varphi n}}{n!}.$$
Eulers formula tell us that  $e^{ix}=\cos x+i\sin x,\,x\in\mathbb{R}.$ From now on you should be able to calculate the last steps. Hint: $r^n/n!$ is real so you can first take the real part of $e^{i\varphi n}$ and then multiply it.

Comment: Does this work in general for any analytic power series? And what about power series which do not expand about the origin?

Comment: You either may set $z-z_0=re^{i\varphi}$ or set $z=re^{i\varphi}$ and have $(re^{i\varphi}-z_0)^n$.  If you use the first method that's gonna give nicer the terms but is not exactly what you want. The second one is what you want but it's hard to find a nice simplification. So in general - it does always work, just don't expect the values to be nice for every power series.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is looking for the answer to this question, you need to take into account that if the function is the real part of an analytic function then the function must be infinitely differentiable (as an analytic function is itself infinitely differentiable). Thus, it can be represented as a power series, and thus fulfill the definition of real-analyticity. The one caveat one needs consider, however, is that the power series will be in two dimensions, and the expansion thereof must reflect a two-dimensional Taylor series.

With this in mind, one can show that a harmonic function on an open domain of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is real-analytic (as it can be proven that a harmonic function is the real/imaginary part of an analytic function).