# Is the real part of a complex analytic function, real analytic?

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

Recently in Calculus 1 we were introduced to the concept of analytic functions (to be more exact, real analytic functions). At the same time I was familiar with the concept of complex analytic functions (being defined as complex functions that are differentiable). I was wondering whether the real part of a complex analytic function is itself real analytic (ie. it has a local Taylor series expansions around any point defined in the function). And why?

the closest answer I've seen in here is the answer from Seth(user:883910) but it wasn't very clear or satisfactory to me:
[Real part of an analytic function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4042312/real-part-of-an-analytic-function)

(also I'd appreciate it if details are presented (but explained at a relatively novice level if possible), and sources which give more information on this are given.)

thanks.

Comment: Well, the domain of the real part of a complex function is still complex numbers, so is a function of two real variables. What is the definition of real analytic for a function of two real variables?

Comment: I don't have a clue . we just covered single variables. Also I don't know whether a double variable function is the same as a complex function (or more generally whether a multivariable function is the same as a multivariable complex function)

Comment: Yes it is. You just need the right definitions. For such details, see Henri Cartan's complex analysis textbook.

Comment: The easiest way to prove is to notice that for $z=x+iy$ we have $z^n=\sum b_{k,n}x^ky^{n-k}$ with complex coefficients $b_{k,n}$ and by absolute convergence one can switch the above in $\sum a_nz^n$ so get both real and imaginary parts as Taylor series in $x,y$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews sorry for acting a little dense. And thanks for indirectly pointing out the taylor series expansion for 2 variable functions.

Comment: @peek-a-boo thanks for the recommendation. Though it is a bit high level for me (now) but I'll look into it.

Comment: @Conrad thanks for the hint. I'll try to figure out the kinks of the derivation (With this and your other comments).